# How to add and remove a fragment programatically?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wish to add a fragment when the device is in landscape mode and remove this fragment when the device is in portrait mode. I was able to add the fragment when the device is in landscape mode. When the device returns to portrait mode I call the remove method, but the fragment still shows.

Below is the code that performs the adding and removing of the fragment:

```
public void addingFragment_programatically()
{
    final String PREF_STATE="preference_state";

    SharedPreferences sPref=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editer=sPref.edit();
    Boolean configState=sPref.getBoolean(PREF_STATE, false);
    Fragment_Base fragment_base=Fragment_Base.newInstance("text passed 
    in during Instantiation","");

    Configuration config=getResources().getConfiguration();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager= getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction       
    fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if(config.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layoutbelow, fragment_base);
        configState=true;
        editer.putBoolean(PREF_STATE,configState);
        editer.commit();

    }
    else if(configState)
    {
        fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment_base);
        configState=false;
        editer.putBoolean(PREF_STATE,configState);
        editer.commit();

    }

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

`R.id.layoutbelow` is a linear layout id that act as the viewGroup for the fragment, it is defined inside the xml layout for this activity class.
I do hope someone can help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragmentObject).commit();
```

worked for me. Can you check your orientation is portrait or landscape in `onConfigurationChanged()` method.

Answer (score 0):

*Works well ... just make the adjustments you need*

**main.java**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameContainer);
    mFragA = new FragmentA();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.frameContainer, mFragA).commit();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .remove(mFragA).commit();

    }else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .add(R.id.frameContainer, mFragA).commit();
    }
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:id="@+id/frameContainer">

</FrameLayout>
```

**manifest**

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            .....
            .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

add  `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in AndroidManifest.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LoginFragment loginFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        // object of fragment
        loginFragment = new LoginFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // landscape mode
        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            // add fragment(where to place, fragment object, fragment tag)
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.loginFrame,loginFragment,"loginFrame").commit();
        }
        // portrait mode
        else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            // remove fragment with passing fragment object
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(loginFragment).commit();
        }

    }
}
```

LoginFragment.java

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // view to render
        View loginView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment,null);
        return loginView;
    }
}
```

This may help you.